# executing linux script with options in expect

Tags: expect, ansible

I am executing `Linux script` in expect mentioned as below.

> spawn "sh /opt/Avaya/CCR/util/CAT/cat.sh --iptfile=no"

I am using `ansible` to execute above command .

when I execute `ansible-playbook catexpect.yml`  then it gives error `file not found`.

Please tell me how to handle this command in expect?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to concatenate the program and args into a single string: just remove the quotes

```
spawn sh /opt/Avaya/CCR/util/CAT/cat.sh --iptfile=no
```